# Alignment and numbering of equations interspersed with tables in the same float

Tags: equations, numbering, subcaption, alignment

I have a question regarding alignment and numbering of equations within a float, but with sub-tables between them.
The problem is that the second batch of equations start a new counter, instead of following the previous sequence. They also are not aligned at the equal symbol, as I'd like. MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[labelfont={tt, scriptsize}, textfont={tt, scriptsize}, position=top]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption[]{Table 1 caption.}\label{tab1:cap}
\subcaptionbox{Subtable 1.\label{tab1:subcap}}
{\begin{tabular}{@{}l c r@{}}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6
\end{tabular}}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{eq1:ex1}
\text{Example 1} & = 1 + 2 + 3 \\
& + 4 + 5 + 6
\end{split} \\
\begin{split}\label{eq1:ex2}
\text{Example 2} & = 1 - 2 - 3 \\
& - 4 - 5 - 6
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\subcaptionbox{Subtable 2.\label{tab2:subcap}}
{\begin{tabular}{@{}l c r@{}}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6
\end{tabular}}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{eq2:ex1}
\text{Ex. 3} & = 1 + 2 + 3 \\
& + 4 + 5 + 6
\end{split} \\
\begin{split}\label{eq2:ex2}
\text{Ex. 4} & = 1 - 2 - 3 \\
& - 4 - 5 - 6
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image: MWE sample]

The idea is to get something similar to this:

[image: Target result]

Note that all equations are aligned at the equal sign, and their reference number is always (1x). Is this possible?

If the tables were long (one sub-table with its respective sub-caption, and one set of equations per page) and I needed to use \ContinuedFloat, so all sub-tables would fall within the same general caption, would it be possible to achieve the same? (particularly the numbering, as the alignment wouldn't be as critical).

Thanks in advance.